# canvas.draw<Figure> draws only for first view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I have a custom view:

```
    class StepView(
        context: Context?,

        @ColorInt
        color: Int,

        private val size: Float
    ) : View(context) {

        private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)

        init {
            paint.color = color
            setWillNotDraw(false)
        }

        fun setColor(@ColorInt color: Int) {
            paint.color = color
            invalidate()
        }

        private fun getCenterX() = x + width / 2

        private fun getCenterY() = y + height / 2

        override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
            super.onDraw(canvas)

            canvas?.drawCircle(getCenterX(), getCenterY(), size / 2, paint)
        }
    }
```

Which is used by another custom view (subclass of LinearLayout):

```
    private fun init(stepCount: Int = defaultStepCount, currentStep: Int = defaultCurrentStep) {
        orientation = HORIZONTAL

        removeAllViews()

        for (i in 0 until stepCount) {
            createStepView(i)
        }
    }

    private fun createStepView(index: Int) {
        val stepView = StepView(context, arrayOf(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK)[index], 20f)
        val layoutParams = LayoutParams(20, 20)

        addView(stepView, layoutParams)
    }
```

All views are added but `canvas?.drawCircle()` (and other methods, line `drawRect()`) works only for the first one:

[image]

Second and third are in layout but not drawn (border is from UiAutomatorViewer; `onDraw` method was called, I've checked with logs and debugger).

If I call `canvas?.drawColor()`, it draws for every view. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas's coordinates are relative to the view, not its parent. When you add the view's `x` and `y` into the return value of `getCenterX()` and `getCenterY()`, respectively, that pushes the figure outside the bounds of the view, making it appear as though nothing is being drawn. To get this to work, simply remove those addends.